# Optimal layout for a chat app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a simple XMPP-based chat app and now considering the ways to create a conversation layout. I plan to add a `LinearLayout` for each message containing the `.9.png` background, the actual text and the timestamp.

**Question 1:** what would fit better for the parent layout to which the message layouts will be added: a Relative- / LinearLayout inside a ScrollView or a ListView?

**Question 2:** what is the most simple way to save those message layouts so the messages stay when the user leaves the activity?

Comment: try looking at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11202206/1056359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1: what would fit better for the parent layout to which the message layouts will be added: a Relative- / LinearLayout inside a ScrollView or a ListView?*

I'd go with `ListView` that way you'll have an `Adapter` and an easy access to each row, listeners, etc.

*Question 2: what is the most simple way to save those message layouts so the messages stay when the user leaves the activity?*

If its gonna be large data the best way is using SQLite DB.
If it's not gonna be that big OR if you're looking for a simple solution - just save the `ArrayList` that represents the chat to file. Many examples are out there for saving Java objects to file and then loading it.

Comment: thanks. But is it possible to insert a layout into a ListView row?

Comment: Sure. You can build and XML layout that will be the layout for each row. And you'll have to implement a custom adapter. Have a look at this: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429